# Unparseable MMM-dd-yyyy

Tags: java, date, parsing

I will be direct with my question. I am wondering why I can't parse a fromat MMM-dd-yyyy into yyyy-MM-dd (java.sql.Date format)? Any suggestion on how I am going to convert a String into a format of (yyyy-MM-dd)?

Here is the code:

```
public DeadlineAction(String deadline){
        putValue(NAME, deadline);
        deadLine = deadline;
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
        try {
            finalDate = (Date) formatter.parse(deadLine);           
        }catch(ParseException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: What value are you trying to parse?

Comment: You can but you would need to parse first into "MMM-dd-yyyy" and then into "yyyy-MM-dd" if you are getting

Comment: Also, there is a difference between `yyyy MM dd` and `MM-dd-yyyy`, but you're trying to parse the second with the first...

Comment: I now got the idea. Thank you for the answer Sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't parse a `String` in the format of `MMM-dd-yyyy` using the format of `yyyy MM dd`, it just doesn't make sense, you need one formatter to parse the value and another to format itm for example

```
SimpleDateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy");

Date date = from.parse(deadLine);
String result = to.format(date)
```

The question that needs to be asked is, why you would bother.  If your intention is to put this value into the database, you should be creating an instance of `java.sql.Date` (from the `java.util.Date`) and using `PreparedStatement#setDate` to apply it to your query, then letting the JDBC driver deal with it

Comment: Hello Sir. Like I said, I cannot parse the "deadLine" variable into date format. My program stops at the parse statement.

Comment: I assume it's because you're trying parse a value which is in the format of `MMM-dd-yyyy` using a parser in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd`, what part of that makes any sense at all?  Did you try using one formatter to parse the `String` to a `Date` and another to format it to the new format? What is the actually value you are trying to parse?

Comment: i think i now get the idea of parsing. thank you for you answer sir. It was a great help!

Comment: Sir it now worked. I got a wrong sense about parsing. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096795/642706) is correct. You must define a formatting pattern to fit the format of your input data string.

You could avoid the problem in the first place by using the java.time framework.

## java.time

The java.time framework is built into Java 8 and later (also back-ported to Java 6 & 7 and to Android). These classes supplant the old troublesome legacy date-time classes (java.util.Date/.Calendar).

## ISO 8601

Your input strings are apparent is standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, YYYY-MM-DD such as `2016-01-23`.

The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating strings that represent date-time values. **So no need to specify a formatting pattern.**

## Parsing string

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2016-01-23" );
```

## Generating string

To generate a string representing that [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) object’s value, just call [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) to get a string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = localDate.toString(); // 2016-01-23
```

For other formats, use the [java.time.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) package. Usually best to let java.time automatically localize to the user’s human language and cultural norms defined by a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM );
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
formatter = formatter.withLocale( locale );
String output = localDate.format( formatter );
```

Or you can specify your own particular pattern. Note that you should still specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine aspects such as the name-of-month or name-of-day. Here is a demo of the pattern that seems to be asked in the Question (not sure as Question is unclear).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM-dd-yyyy" );
Locale locale = Locale.US;
formatter = formatter.withLocale( locale );
String output = localDate.format( formatter );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
try {
    final String deadLine = "Oct-12-2006";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy");//define formatter for yout date time
    Date finalDate = formatter.parse(deadLine);//parse your string as Date
    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");// define your desired format
    System.out.println(formatter2.format(finalDate));//format the string to your desired date format
 } catch (Exception e) {
    //handle
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not unparseable. I removed the dashes from MMM-dd-yyyy to MMM dd yyyy. You can put them back if needed. I also removed the any extra code to make the solution clear.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public DeadlineAction(String deadline){

    //if deadline has format similar to "December 19 2011"
    try {
         finalDate = new java.sql.Date(
                ((java.util.Date) new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy").parse(deadline)).getTime()); 

    }catch(ParseException e) {
       //Your exception code
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This works for almost every conversion to sqlDate. Just change SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy") to what you need it to be.

Example: new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy-dd").parse("NOVEMBER-2012-30")

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. I can’t get the point in answering a question about a different format form the one asked about. Also using `SimpleDateFormat` is poor advice, that class is not only long outdated (along with `java.utilDate` and `java.sql.Date`), it’s also notoriously troublesome.

Comment: The original question: I am wondering why I can't parse a fromat MMM-dd-yyyy into yyyy-MM-dd (java.sql.Date format)?

Comment: The original question: I am wondering why I can't parse a fromat MMM-dd-yyyy into yyyy-MM-dd (java.sql.Date format)?  Simply put, how to parse from this format: December(MMM) - 19(dd) - 2011(yyyy) to java.sql.Date which is yyyy-MM-dd.  The answer I provided used java imports that were mentioned or used in the question or example code. I definitely answered about the same, I repeat, the same format adrian quevada asked about. SimpleDateFormat was used in question example code and java.sql.Date format was used in question and question example code. Also, not outdated and troublesome to all.

Comment: I just didn’t get the point in removing the dashes, that was what I meant by “different format”.