# can't convert String to MMM/dd/yyy format in java

Tags: java, java-time, datetimeformatter

I try to convert an input type `String` into `LocalDate` with format `"MMM/dd/yyyy"`, but when I enter input, it throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
> Text 'DEC/12/1999' could not be parsed at index 0

Here is my code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
DateTimeFormatter format1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.print("Please enter the first date: ");
LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.parse(sc.nextLine(), format1);
System.out.print("Please enter the second date: ");
System.out.println(firstDate);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: might be the locale. Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096757/unparseable-mmm-dd-yyyy

Comment: Note that month names and abbreviations are depending on the Locale so make sure you're using a Locale that uses "DEC". Try `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);`. What I'm also not sure if the names are case-sensitive or not, so you might try "Dec" or "dec" if "DEC" doesn't work with the locale.

Comment: thanks verymuch, i will try then review it

Comment: it's work with parseCaseInsensitive and Locale, thanks very much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take care of several things when parsing a `String` like `"DEC/12/1999"`:

- abbreviations of months do not have a global standard, they differ in language (e.g. English, French, Japanese...) and style (e.g. trailing dot or not)
- there's a difference in parsing lower-case month abbreviations and those in upper-case

That's why you have to make sure your `DateTimeFormatter` really knows what to do, I think it won't do if simply build by `.ofPattern(String, Locale)`.

Give it information about the `String` to be parsed:

- make it parse case-insensitively by applying `parseCaseInsensitive()`
- make it consider language and style by defining a `Locale`

You can use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` in order to do that, here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // example input
    String date = "DEC/12/1999";
    // Build a formatter, that...
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                // parses independently from case,
                                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                // parses Strings of the given pattern
                                .appendPattern("MMM/dd/uuuu")
                                // and parses English month abbreviations.
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    // Then parse the String with the specific formatter
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dtf);
    // and print the result in a different format.
    System.out.println(localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
}
```

Output:

```
1999-12-12
```